# Openstack CLI does not honour project scope

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Is it possible to scope Openstack CLI output for listing networks only for a single project. I have tried multiple options like --os-project-id, --os-project-name etc but it seems to list down all networks across multiple projects/tenants.

Currently, the command I am using is:

> openstack network list --os-username XXX --os-password YYY --os-project-id ZZZ

Note: The credentials that I am using here are of an 'admin' account

Parameters set in the environment are :

```
OS_PROJECT_ID=XXX
OS_REGION_NAME=XXX
OS_TENANT_ID=XXX
OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=XXX
OS_PROJECT_NAME=XXX
OS_AUTH_VERSION=XXX
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=XXX
OS_PASSWORD=XXX
OS_AUTH_URL=XXX
OS_USERNAME=XXX
OS_TENANT_NAME=XXX
OS_INTERFACE=XXX
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=XXX
```

Comment: can you run the command with `--no-share` option?

Comment: Can you check whether you have V3 support enabled for keystone?

Comment: Anyway, I think you get your information if the user has `_member_`  role instead of `admin`

Comment: @kuro Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using '--no-share' option but still get the same output.

Comment: @kuro How can I check if keystone supports v3 ? I already have OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3 set in my environment variables

Comment: You can check if in openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py, OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_MULTIDOMAIN_SUPPORT is set to True or not

Answer (score 0):

May be your networks are shared by all tenants. If you only have a few networks you can verify with `neutron net-show Network-Name` and review the `shared` attribute

BTW I use the env variable `OS_PROJECT_NAME` to switch between projects

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked for network attributes and only few of them are shared. However, the output of the command lists down many more networks than I would expect

Answer (score 0):

Without any explicit filter specified in the parameters, Neutron's network API returns *all* networks that the user accessing the API has privileges to list. The recommended way to scope down the list of networks to a specific project is to explicitly specify that filter.

Via CLI, you can scope the list to a specific project "demo" using the following example:

```
openstack network list --project demo
```

You can see more filtering options via the help text:

```
openstack help network list
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried these already, but doesn't seem to work. Also added the list of environment variables that are set in the environment

Comment: @akskap When you scope it to a specific tenant/project, are you still getting the response with all networks?

Comment: @akskap, which version of OpenStack are you running? Against Ocata when I use "--project demo" argument, I see only those networks that are associated with the demo project.

Comment: We are using Openstack Newton with OpenStack CLI version 3.13.0 ... did you try with admin credentials which is also a domain admin ?

Answer (score 0):

Issues were caused by an older version of Openstack CLI v3.7.0

Using Openstack CLI version v3.13.0, I was able to solve my requirement. By default, with the domain admin account, the CLI still dumped the entire network list but with the --long flag, the 'project' field this time was populated and I could filter out the results for the specific project.

This was not the case with the previous CLI versions. Usage of '--long' flag had all the values of 'Project' as none.